# Interior regularity for parabolic systems in divergence form

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, regularity

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$, $n \in \mathbb N$, be a smooth, bounded domain. Suppose $N \in \mathbb N$, $D \subset \mathbb R^N$ and that $a_{ij} : D \to \mathbb R$ are smooth for $i, j \in \{1, \dots, N\}$ and such that the real parts of all eigenvalues of $A := (a_{ij})_{ij}$ have a positive lower bound. (However, do neither assume that $A$ is symmetric nor that $A$ is elliptic in the sense that $\sum_{i,j=1}^N a_{ij}(u) \xi_i \xi_j \ge c |\xi|^2$.)

I was able to construct (for specific $A$, of course) a weak solution $u : \Omega \times [0, \infty) \to D$ to the parabolic system

$$u_t = \nabla \cdot (A(u) \cdot \nabla u)$$

in the sense that there is $p \gt n$ such that

$$u \in C^0([0, T]); W^{1, p}(\Omega)) \cap C^1((0, T); W^{-1, p}(\Omega) \qquad \text{for all } T \gt 0$$

(in particular, $u$ is Hölder continuous)
and the equation is fulfilled in the sense that

$$
   \int_\Omega u_{i t}(\cdot, t) \varphi
 = - \sum_{j=1}^N \int_\Omega a_{ij}(u(\cdot, t)) \nabla u_j(\cdot, t) \cdot \nabla \varphi \qquad \text{for all } t > 0, \varphi \in C_c^\infty(\Omega) \text{ and } i \in \{1, \dots, N\}.
$$

Note that this does not include any information on the behavior of $u$ on $\partial \Omega$.

---

Next, my intention was to infer from parabolic regularity theory that $u$ is in fact smooth. If I knew that $u$ fulfilled some boundary condition (say, $u(\cdot, t) \in W_0^{1, p}(\Omega)$ for all $t > 0$), then uniqueness results by Amann [1, Theorem 14.4] would indeed imply smoothness of $u$.

For the corresponding proof, Amann inter alia relies on the results from Solonnikov [2] and while I was able to find the Russian original paper, my searches for the English translation (which MathSciNet claims to exist) have not been fruitful. (As a side note, I am happy for any pointers to the translated article.)

In any case, I would expect to obtain interior regularity, that is $u \in C^{2, 1}(\Omega \times (0, T))$ simply by applying “standard” results. As I am unable to find these results in the literature, **I would like to ask for references implying that the solution above is smooth in $\Omega \times (0, T)$.**

Most of the times, I rely on regularity theory for *single parabolic equations* even when studying systems. That seems insufficient here (and may be the reason I am so unfamiliar with the corresponding literature).

I have also tried the following idea, sadly without any success:
As $u$ is (Hölder-) continuous on the boundary, one idea is to consider the system which should be solved by $u - g_k$, where $g_k : \overline \Omega \times [0, T] \to \mathbb R^N$ is smooth and converges in $C^0(\partial \Omega \times [0, T])$ to $u|_{\partial \Omega \times [0, T]}$. Amann [1] then provides smooth solutions $u_k$ to this new problem which *should* converge in good norms to $u$. However, there are two problems: First, Amann does not (or at least not directly) give any quantitative bounds for the solutions (which would hopefully imply that $(u_k)_k$ is a Cauchy sequence in certain spaces) and second, one would still have to prove uniqueness for the original system.

---

References:

[1] Amann, H.: *Nonhomogeneous linear and quasilinear elliptic and parabolic boundary value problems*. In Schmeisser, H. and Triebel, H., editors, Function Spaces, Differential Operators and Nonlinear Analysis, pages 9–126. [MR1242579](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=MR&s1=1242579)

[2] Solonnikov, V. A.: *On boundary value problems for linear parabolic systems of differential equations of general form*. Trudy
Mat. Inst. Steklov., 83:3–163, 1965. [MR211083](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?r=1&pg1=MR&s1=211083)